# Modifying weight and dimension units from letters to full words on WooCommerce product descriptions on the frontend

Tags: woocommerce, frontend, meter

I wish to change WooCommerce Weight text from letter "G" to "Grams" in products description front end. All so about dimensions from letter "M" to "Meters"

[WooCommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu4n8.png)

dose anyone have any idea how to change that text in frond end ?

I don't use any plugin for this